# Does this improper integral converge or is it a trick question?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I have this improper integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2}\ dx$$

During my lecture we were told to find whether it converges or diverges, and I found it converged because after calculating the integral:

$$ \frac{-e^{-x^2}}{2}$$

I can see adding infinity for x will make the fraction $=0$. We were told it was a trick question, something something about negatives, and we moved on. But I'm still wondering why the answer isn't that it converges because it still looks correct to me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value are good reads.
This comment is copied from a [similar question asked by me](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028297/why-dont-all-odd-functions-integrate-to-0-from-infty-to-infty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x) = x e^{-x^2}$ is infinitely often differentiable and has an antiderivative $F(x) = -\frac12 e^{-x^2}$ everywhere on $\mathbb R$. The improper  integral is defined by
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = \lim_{y\to-\infty}\int_y^c f(x)\,dx + \lim_{y\to\infty} \int_c^y f(x)\,dx $$
With this knowledge we get
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = \lim_{y\to-\infty}\bigl(F(c) - F(y)\bigr) + \lim_{y\to\infty} \bigl(F(y) - F(c)\bigr) = -\lim_{y\to\infty}e^{-y^2} = 0$$
since $F$ is symmetric and the limit is obvious.

I don't think it's a trick question, but it is not a proper integral because Riemann integrals only work for bounded intervals. But these improper integrals are nevertheless well-defined (as *im*proper integrals).

The only thing that *could* potentially be tricky is that there are integrals over infinitely long intervals, where the improper Riemann integral does *not* coincide with the Lebesgue integral (which works on unbounded intervals on its own).

Comment: I am not sure I would call it a "trick question" but the "trick" to answering it quickly is to observe that the integrand is an **odd** function.  The integral from any -a to a is 0.

Comment: Oh, well yes. But when handling improper integrals one should not rely on intuition too much.

Comment: Thanks Wauzl, after starring at this question for about 2 hours now it's nice to know I wasn't crazy

Comment: @user247327 One can get in trouble applying this line of reasoning to improper integrals: The function $x \mapsto \frac{x}{1 + x^2}$ is odd but $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \,dx}{1 + x^2}$ is divergent.

Comment: @Travis Thank you for providing this example! We can clearly see that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = \lim_{y\to-\infty}\int_y^c f(x)\,dx + \lim_{y\to\infty} \int_c^y f(x)\,dx \neq \lim_{y\to\infty}\int_{-y}^y f(x)\,dx$ in general!

Comment: @Wauzl You're welcome. That particular example is discussed in detail in this recent question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2229944/calculate-int-infty-infty-fracx1x2dx-what-is-wrong-with-this